# Appropriate word for very fast

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

Can some one tell me the appropriate word instead of 'very fast' in sentence:

> Don't loose hope *very fast*.

Comment: This might be an ELL.se issue, as it sounds unnatural in more than one way.  I would welcome more context.  "Quickly" may be the adverb you're after.

Comment: You seem to mean *too early* rather.

Comment: This is a common error: *loose* in your example should be *lose*. *Lose* is a verb; *loose* is an adjective.

Answer (score 1):

*Straightaway or right away* are  useful expressions:

> without delay; immediately or promptly

Examples:

> - If you have been attacked call the police straightaway.
> - Our aim is to resolve your complaint straightaway.

Source: http://sentence.yourdictionary.com

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that most native speakers would express this instruction as :

> Don't lose hope too soon.